# Comprobar valor en html laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, foreach

Me gustaría saber si puedo comparar el dato que recibo del array en el html pero no me deja porque lo obtengo con un echo.

```
@foreach($listado as $ganancia)
        <tr>
            @if ({{ $ganancia->dinero }} > 0)
            <td>{!! $ganancia->fecha !!}</td>
            <td><p style="color:green";>{!! $ganancia->dinero !!}€</p></td>
            @else
            <td>{!! $ganancia->fecha !!}</td>
            <td><p style="color:red">;{!! $ganancia->dinero !!}€</p></td>
            @endif
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

Funciona bien sin el if y el else pero cuando intento eso ya no funciona

Comment: ¿No debería ser `@if ($ganancia->dinero > 0)`?

Comment: esta parte la tienes mal: `@if ({{ $ganancia->dinero }} > 0)` pues al usar `{{}}` estás indicando que el valor en cuestión se imprima, debería bastar con quitarlas y dejar el resto del `if` igual

Comment: estas mal colocado para validar desde el blade es @if($ganancia->dinero>0) @endif

Answer (score 0):

Los corchetes dobles funcionan directamente para imprimir.
si vas a hacer una comparación deberia ser asi:

```
@if ( $ganancia->dinero  > 0)
        <td>{{ $ganancia->fecha }}</td>
        <td><p style="color:green";>{{ $ganancia->dinero }}€</p></td>
@endif
```

En resumen tu código quedaría de esta forma:

```
@foreach($listado as $ganancia)
    <tr>
        @if ( $ganancia->dinero > 0)
          <td>{{ $ganancia->fecha }}</td>
          <td><p style="color:green";>{{ $ganancia->dinero }}€</p></td>
        @else
          <td>{{ $ganancia->fecha }}</td>
          <td><p style="color:red">;{{ $ganancia->dinero }}€</p></td>
        @endif
    </tr>
@endforeach
```